# r function for classifying spring vs neap tides

Tags: r

I used the ‘VulnToolkit’ to bring in tidal station data. I want to classify each tide reading as spring or neap tide. Is there another function or package to do this?

I am trying to match foraging behaviors of a water bird to when it occurred in the spring or neap tidal cycle. Thanks.

Comment: Its best to add some data and some code to show what you have tried and what you are expecting.

Comment: Also, a general definition of neap and spring tides would be helpful.

Comment: Greetings! As another has noted, it is helpful to provide what code you have used already to work through your problem, some data you are using, or some version of desired results into your question.